# Server Redirect with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, authentication

I call this function from another page

```
  Redirect($loc);
```

and I want it to redirect my server..

```
function Redirect($loc) 
{    
   echo ("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var timeout=1; setTimeout(\"window.location.replace('" . $loc . "')\", timeout*1000 );</script>");    
}
```

I have two questions. one is the script in the function is correct?
second, how do I pass it a url, assuming I am using the localhost and I want my applicaton to be portable. So I my file is called Registration.php and it is in the Users folder of my site, how do I contruct a url?

Comment: What do you mean how do you construct a URL? You would simply pass `/Users/Registration.php` to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason that you're using Javascript to redirect? What if the client has Javascript disabled?

A better way to perform redirection would be to do it server-side like such:

```
function redirect($location)
{
    header('Location: ' . $location);
    die();
}
```

That will send the location header to the browser thus redirect it immediately, saving you bandwidth and the possibility that Javascript is disabled on the client side.

Note that as this is a header, you will need to either call this method before you have output any data (with `echo` or otherwise), or use [output buffering](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) so as to not have to change your application much.

---

As described in comment to cover a relative URL, you could use a constant storing your web root which would work like this (replace line):

```
header('Location: ' . WEB_ROOT . $location);
```

---

Example usage:

```
<?php
define('WEB_ROOT', '/');
function redirect($location) 
{
    header('Location: ' . WEB_ROOT . $location);
    die();
}
redirect('Users/Registration.php');
```

Comment: hmm..thanks I havent thought about it. how can I construct my relative path

Comment: don't forget to say that he can send this redirect only before any browser output, also would be nice to describe meta redirects :)

Comment: Does it need to be relative? Generally a good way would be to have a central variable (config file?) where you're storing the web root then append your location from that?

Comment: @user973254 A meta redirection is nasty, but added note about header.

Comment: hmm..so when I upload , for example home.php, will it have my web server url name www.forum/home.php instead of localhost/home.php

Comment: what do you mean before the browser output, I want it to be triggered like an event.. lets say when a user presses a button

Comment: That's not the definition of relative! But either way, you don't need to pass the domain name at all. If you pass `/Users/Registration.php` to the function in my answer, it will redirect to `http://whateverdomain.com/Users/Registration.php`.

Comment: @Matrix001 PHP is server-side, not client side. It is certainly not an event driven language.

Comment: lol..not like asp.net..cause I find it longer to program in php

Comment: Thats what I get by the way: http://localhost/PoliticalForum/User_Pages/WEB_ROOT .. it says the object wasnt found  or this if I dont include the web_root Notice: Undefined variable: location in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\untitled\ServerRedirect.php on line 5

Comment: @Matrix001 ASP.NET is server-side/non-event-driven too. It just has magic methods like their 'postbacks' that will run code on the server side and put the returned HTML back into the document. You will find information on how to do this in PHP by Googling for 'PHP AJAX', or something... It's a lot quicker to code something up in PHP than ASP.NET.

Comment: @Matrix001 Yes you will get that, you need to define it with something like this: `define('WEB_ROOT', '/');`...

Comment: by the way,,this is what I get with your redirect function Object not found! http://localhost/StoredProcedure/User/login.php

Comment: @Matrix001 Please read my post again. The final line in my answer replaces the one *within* the function, it should not be put anywhere on it's own.

Comment: sorry..all I get is object not found,, no matter where I put the WEBROOT, or if i use it or not

Comment: it doesnt work..cause it adds the address from which I am sendin from to where I want to send..making a mix out of things

Comment: @Matrix001 updated my answer with full example usage... It's not difficult, just ensure there's a leading `/` otherwise it will be parsed as a relative URL by the browser.

Comment: I tried the same algorithm it doesn work..Object not found : It gives me this http://localhost/mainHome.php ..I copied and pasted what you gave me

Answer (score 1):

This is more suitable for redirection than yours, to make you application portable use relative paths, not absolute ones

```
function redirect($where = '') {
    if(!empty($where)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $where . '";</script>';
        exit(); // to prevent script execution if user switched off JS
    }       
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this: "../StoredProcedure/User/login.php"

Comment: I know nothing about your app structure, but you can try by yourself